# Extract information from both the filename and the contents of the file

Tags: text-processing, scripting, filenames

I have generated a bunch of files which all contain just one number. I then have some information about these files in each filename. What I want to do, is to collect all file contents as a column in a new file, and then get some part of each filename as separate columns in this new file.

The filenames look like this: `traj-num1-iter-num2-states-num3.gradient`, where num1, num2, and num3 are just different numbers. An example of what I want:

```
$ cat traj-10-iter-220-states-01.gradient
-0.0014868599999999788

$ cat newfile
traj    iter     states    gradient
10      220      01        -0.0014868599999999788
```

I suspect this can be achieved, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using AWK’s `FILENAME` variable:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; print "traj", "iter", "states", "gradient"; FS="-|\\." } { gradient=$0; $0=FILENAME; print $2, $4, $6, gradient }' traj-*-iter-*-states-*.gradient
```

will output the requested header line, then process each `traj-*-iter-*-states-*.gradient` file, outputting the values extracted from its filename, and its contents.

The following variant, based on a [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360937/extract-information-from-both-the-filename-and-the-contents-of-the-file/360938?noredirect=1#comment639519_360938) by [Olivier Dulac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27616/olivier-dulac), extracts the header line from the filename and uses a simpler version of `FS`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; FS="[-.]" } { contents=$0; $0=FILENAME; if (!header) { print $1, $3, $5, $7; header=1 }; print $2, $4, $6, contents }' traj-*-iter-*-states-*.gradient
```

You can change the glob at the end to match whichever files you’re interested in, and the header will adapt (to the first file that’s processed).

Comment: Did not know about the `FILENAME` variable, that can come in handy thank you !

Comment: An answer taking care of this just based on FILENAME and its content (ie, without pre-assuming than FILENAME contains "iter" or "states" or "traj", but finding those out from FILENAME itself) : `awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t"; FS="[.-]" }   { lastvalue=$0 ; $0=FILENAME; print $1, $3, $5, $7 ; print $2, $4, $6, lastvalue }' traj*.gradient`  (note: `[.]`  matches only a litteral `.` and is more readable than `\\.` imo

Comment: I don't fully understand the syntax of "FS="-|\\."". You set the field separator to be what, exactly? Both a "dash" and a "dot"? What does the "\\" mean?

@OlivierDulac does the order of "[.-]" matter? Would "[-.]" be the same?

Comment: Yes, `FS` is set to match either a `-` or an actual `.`; `-|\\.` is one way of writing that as a regex for AWK (the `.` needs to be escaped, because `.` in a regex means “any character”). @Olivier’s `[.-]` form is a more readable variant.

Comment: @Olivier thanks for the suggestion, I’ve adapted it and added it to my answer (with a filter to avoid printing the header for every file processed).

Comment: @Yoda:  `[a-z]` means "any character that, in your locale, is between `a` and `z` (so: "a" or "b" or ... or "z" if you use for example LC_ALL="C" (locale C, meaning the regular ascii letters),  or in some other locales it could be: "a" "A" "b" "B" ... "y" "Y" "z" (and not "Z") , for exemple in many utf-* locales, etc) ,  but `[a-]` will means "either `a` or `-`"  because `-` comes last (ie, when you have `-` as the **last** element inside a `[]`, it is taken as a litteral "-").  And usually in regular expressions, "." is "any character", but inside "[]" it becomes: the litteral "." character.

Comment: Just a short follow-up: is it possible to print in this table as a separate column the content (one number) from a different set of files?

Comment: It is possible, but it’s probably worth asking a separate question.